# Can I use the Office Add-ins platform to automate Outlook?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-addins

I'm using the Windows desktop version of Outlook 365.  I very frequently create a new Outlook 'task' and add the exact same text (with formatting) to the description section.  I would like to automate this, so that all this is done with a single keystroke (or maybe mouse click).  Can this be done with the [Office Add-ins platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins)?  I am a web developer, so using JavaScript is appealing.

If not, how might I approach this?  I've tried VBA but the process was a bit difficult, which is why I'm hoping I can use a JavaScript approach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Addin is an overkill - it will need to be installed in your Exchange tenant or sideloaded.

VBA is not at all difficult if you already know JS.

Comment: "Addin is an overkill" OK. But it can do what I want--correct?  If so, what drawbacks would you say it has, other than having to be installed in my Exchange tenant?

"it will need to be installed in your Exchange tenant" Isn't that done with just a few clicks in my MS365 admin area?

Comment: Sure, if you are the admin.Which is not the case for most Outlook users.

Comment: OK got it.  So aside from that, do you think using the Office Add-ins to accomplish what I want would have any other drawbacks?  I've never used it, but am a bit curious.

Comment: You need to be more specific what it is exactly that you want to do - the web addin API still lags light years behind OOM in term of functionality.

Comment: OK here are the specifics.  I very frequently create a new Outlook 'task' (using the desktop version of Outlook365) and to the task description, add the exact same text.  It is just a few lines of text, but the text requires bold formatting, as well a very specific bullet style. I would like to automate this, so that the creation of this task, as well as the addition of the text, is all done with a single keystroke (or maybe mouse click).  Is that enough details, or would you need more?  I’m happy to provide more if it helps.